# HTTP 500 Error but does store data to database - Wordpress new-post.php, post.php, edit-post.php not working after updating data structure and plugins

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post, wp-admin

The wordpress function "get_default_post_to_edit" inside the "post.php" file located at "wp-admin/includes/" is not working correctly.

When I am loading the page: wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product :I get an HTTP 500 error, but it does store a record inside my database, but $post_id echo's '0' (which is not 0 in the new record).

When I comment out the line below, in this function I mention above, I get no HTTP 500 error, but my page is not working correctly:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array( 'post_title' => __( 'Auto Draft' ), 'post_type' => $post_type, 'post_status' => 'auto-draft' ) );
```

When I add the following code after the $post_id = wp_insert_post(.... it echo's 'NULL':

```
exit(var_dump( $wpdb->last_query));
```

When I try to save the product page, it tells me I don't have the permission to  do that.

Also when I try to edit an earlier posted product I can retrieve all information, but when I try to save the changes it throws me an HTTP 500 error again in the script "post.php" from this code:

```
    $success = wp_update_post( $post_data );
```

How I can debug or troubleshoot wordpress in those kind of situations?

### Edit

I just noticed that I can't add, edit or delete anything using WordPress without getting an HTTP 500 Error, but it does add/edit/delete the content to the database.

All of this happend after I've updated WooCommerce and some other plugins and updated the data structure, I have compared my new scripts to my old scripts but I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the update of WooCommerce 3.0.3 which broke the full site down..
Have downgraded again and am now reading how to migrate properly..
Apparently  this was a Major upgrade at which they have moved to a new "CRUD" -method, basicly adding another layer between website and database..

Scroll down on this site below untill you see the part about: *Upgrading to 3.0*
https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/say-hello-to-woocommerce-3-0-bionic-butterfly/

EDIT: most of the problems are fixed by reading migration notes of woocommerce, but the backend working with post.php e.g. was because of a third party plugin that wasnt compatible with woocommerce 3.0.